# Do I need to ask permission to track using OneSignal?

Tags: ios, flutter, onesignal

I am not sure if it's necessary to ask user permission to track with AppTrackingTransparency framework using OneSignal Flutter SDK.

The only think I use OneSignal is receve Push Notifications and get the user userId in OSSubscriptionState from OneSignal then send userId to my API.

In my main.dart

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  if (!mounted) return;

  await OneSignal.shared.init(oneSignalAppId, iOSSettings: {
    OSiOSSettings.autoPrompt: false,
    OSiOSSettings.promptBeforeOpeningPushUrl: true
  });
}
```

Then

```
OSPermissionSubscriptionState status =
            await OneSignal.shared.getPermissionSubscriptionState();
// send status.subscriptionStatus.userId to API
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faith from OneSignal said:

> There is no need to show such a notice to users as we are not tracking
> anything.

So there is no need to ask permission to track using OneSignal.